# session data missing in asp.net sometimes only

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, session

My asp.net application hosted to azure recently, after that we facing a issue which is losing data in session, this is not happening all the times but randomly happening but when it was hosted in IIS this issue was not happening.

We have a custom entity list and there is an file upload facility when user uploads file we saves into DB at the same time keeping it in session, while they upload 'N' number of files application successfully processed and saved into both DB and session. But after saved (here button click event) in the same lifecycle when comes to page load, data is missing. I checked/debugged there are no codes changing session data in between these events.

Note: This issue happening only in server not in localhost.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] and the contents of your web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

In case it worked on IIS, but not on Azure.
It sounds like a Session Timeout issue (likely to be global server settings).
I would suggest adding explicitly session timeout in your `web.config` file.

```
<system.web>
 <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="80" />
</system.web>
```

> **InProc mode**, which stores session state in memory on the Web server. This is the default.
>
> **cookieless=false**, if no requests are treated as cookieless.
>
> **timeout**, Specifies the number of minutes a session can be idle before it is abandoned.

Read more at [MSDN Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I notice that Azure is tagged in the question.

In Azure, we are supposed to run a *least* two instances which is basically web-farm environment. As the result, we need to use **Redis Cache**.

You just create Redis Cache in Azure, and add the following to **web.config**.

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RedisConnection" connectionString="REDIS_CONNECTION_STRING" 
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>    
    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="SessionStateStore">
      <providers>
        <add name="SessionStateStore" 
          type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
          connectionString="RedisConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
<configuration>
```

The quick and dirty way to make it works **without Redis Cache** is to turn on the **Affinity Cookie** in Azure Portal. However, it is not recommended, because you cannot scale the application.

[image]